# Old song with lyric "Number 9 with a brass plate on the door"

Tags: lyrics, identify-this-song

My grandfather often used to sing a snippet of an old song. My mother and I are curious as to what the song is, but we've not been able to find it with Google. I wondered if anyone here happened to know it?

The lyrics, as far as he ever sang them:

*It's gone, it's gone, wherever can it be?*
*Wherever it has gone to is a mystery to me*
*Oh I have searched so long*
*I can't search any more*
*Has anyone seen Number 9 with a brass plate on the door?*

Comment: Perhaps if you could guess the style of the song (bluegrass for example) and said what area he was from that may help. My google-fu failed with your lyrics.

Comment: We're from the UK, I'd guess at maybe music hall for the style?

Comment: Is it possible that this was a very localized (folk)song from.. let's say, your grandfather's school or something? Again, googling the lyric didn't return any satisfying result.

Comment: or, he could have made it up himself, in the style of a music-hall song